# Using USB PS2 hand controller in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I'm attempting to create a program that takes input from a usb ps2 hand controller, translate and passes the info to a rs232 device. I already have everything working for the rs232 device. The problem is interfacing with a usb controller. There doesn't seem to be any good documentation out there and on top of that .NET3.0/3.5 doesn't have any libs to help you out. How would one even get started?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried SharpUSBLib for accessing the usb data?

Answer (score 0):

it may be a few years old thread...anywho.... I know SlimDX is a pretty good library for C#.Net/VB. And, to use a USB controller, it is very simple, all you need to do is something like this. Note, this code I made on the fly and I don't have joystick to test it, and this...

```
    static Joystick[] joystick = new Joystick[1];
const int minimum_value = -1000;//your values goes here
const int maximum_value = 1000;//your values goes here

public test()
{
    DirectInput USBJoystick = new DirectInput();
    IList<DeviceInstance> device = null;//to get the joysticks
    device = USBJoystick.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameController, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly);
    if (device.Count == 1)
        joystick[0] = new Joystick(USBJoystick, device[0].InstanceGuid);

    foreach (DeviceObjectInstance deviceObject in joystick[0].GetObjects())
    {
        if ((deviceObject.ObjectType & ObjectDeviceType.Axis) != 0)
            joystick[0].GetObjectPropertiesById((int)deviceObject.ObjectType).SetRange(minimum_value, maximum_value);
    }
}
```