# C# Gamepad Input/Output Class

Tags: c#, joystick, playstation

I am trying to design a little program that takes input from two PS2 controllers from a USB converter. I would like to take input from all the buttons including pressing the joysticks in (L3, R3), and the joysticks position, and whether the analog is on. I would also like to send feedback back to the controllers and run the two vibration motors and possibly control the LED for analog.

What I'm looking for is a C# source code file that can do it all or an already compiled all-in-one DLL or even a beginners tutorial.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913203/using-usb-ps2-hand-controller-in-c-net

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to develop a .NET library of your own to interface with a PlayStation controller, and this could get pretty involved. This [article](http://www.gamesx.com/controldata/psxcont/psxcont.htm) can help get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Its an interesting article that will come in handy but I dont see how I can turn it in to code. Thanks for the swift response and I'm sure I can apply it but I still need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16704/Interfacing-with-a-Joystick-using-C

Also read: `http://213.55.83.214:8181/Computer%20Science/Programming/01428.pdf`

Not the entire book but parts that are relevant for what you need.